# Error when adding excerpt to the content through functions.php

Tags: php, functions, excerpt, content

I am trying to add the excerpt from a specific post to the content.

```
function add_2_the_content( $content ) {
  if (is_front_page()){
      $custom_content = get_the_excerpt('some_id_number');
  }
  $custom_content .= $content;
return $custom_content;
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_2_the_content' );
```

But when I do this I get an error.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Maximum function nesting level of '256' reached, aborting!
```

I have searched for this error but have not found an answer that would explain why it is not working with get_the_excerpt.

Comment: Where and how are you using `add_2_the_content()`?

Comment: It is placed in my functions.php, it is the minimized code to extract the error. The end goal will be to show multiple excerpt from different posts on the front page.